# Enable WebGL when running nighwatch.js/selenium framework on chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium, webgl, selenium-chromedriver

I came up with a strange issue happening when I try to launch a page having some WebGL content using a nightwatchJS-based framework:

1. If i open the page content directly using chrome, WebGL is detected properly. chrome://gpu/ --> Graphics Feature Status indicates that most of features are harware accelerated
2. If i open the page using nightwatch, WebGL is not detected (and chrome://gpu/ --> Graphics Feature Status indicates that most of features are software only)
3. If i open chrome manually, then launch the nightwatch process, WebGL is not detected in the new chrome session (and chrome://gpu/ --> Graphics Feature Status indicates that most of features are software only)
4. If i open chrome manually, then launch nightwatch process using the same session profile, the page is NOT loaded, but chrome://gpu/ --> Graphics Feature Status indicates that most of features are hardware accelerated

Important detail: it was working fine until end of august, before chrome was updated. Then I tried to update my version of chromedriver, but it did not work either. Chrome does not allow to downgrade to a particular version and is automatically installing updates.

Has anyone ever made a webgl page work with nightwatch ? If so, can you point me to the right thing to do to force WebGL and hardware acceleration to be enabled and load the page through nightwatch interface on a default/custom session ?

Comment: hi did you find a solution to your problem? I have google chrome installed on a linux box and running nightwatch tests using the linux chrome driver, but i'm not able to use my website because of lack of web gl support.

Comment: yes, see my own solution below, hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using these options makes it work!

```
"chromeOptions": { "args": ["user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data", "--ignore-gpu-blacklist", "--use-gl", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-web-security"] },
```

(replace user_name with the proper value)

Comment: Thanks, though I think only the args `--ignore-gpu-blacklist` and `--use-gl` are relevant here?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have just shown also the other options that I was using locally since these are necessary to this particular setup. Remote virtual machine in my case. I love complex setups :)

Comment: We were able to have web-gl support without the user-data/profile args, just `--ignore-gpu-blacklist` and `use-gl` worked. This will not work if you also have `--disable-gpu`.